# I need to find out how to use a URLConnection object to act like a WebView

Tags: android, post, webview, user-agent, urlconnection

I am using a URLConnection to connect to a website and send a POST request but I get an error page response because it can't detect my browser. How can I send the page my user agent string and other pieces it needs?

I know the error I get is only given when it can't detect the browser being used or detects one that isn't compatible with the site. I have created a WebView on the same application and used it to successfully log into the site. I used the built in browser and successfully logged into the site.

This is being developed on an Android phone SDK 2.3.3 Level 10.

Please reply here to answer or ask any questions about the problem.
Joshua.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the http header that the browser that you want to emulate is sending and set up your URLConnection so that it will look similar.

Use this for assistance on doing that:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html